# Laravel Lumen 7 permission denied tymon/jwt-auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt, composer-php

I'm trying to clone a Github repo that uses the tymon/jwt-auth package, however, when I run `composer install` it complains about permissions on the `.zip` folder, this folder doesn't exist, but I would've thought composer would install this, any ideas?

composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "^7.0",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-develop"
}
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Lumen 7 use
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0",

Comment: Please explain that further - why exactly should another version be used, and why shouldn't that trigger the exact same problem?